# Do a floor tile or dry sand conduct electricity?

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics, electrical-resistance, geophysics

If you touch an electric wire while standing on a ground made of soil or floor tile, you will get electrocuted. So, electricity passes through it. Right? Shall I conduct an experiment by passing current through dry sand or tile? Will it work?

Comment: I've just measured the resistance of my floor tiles using my multimeter and they are good insulators. So the premise of your question looks wrong.

Comment: Then why I'm getting electrocuted while standing on floor tiles?

Comment: You have metal floor tiles?

Comment: Are you touching multiple wires when you do this by any chance?

Comment: No only the phase wire

Comment: @JohnRennie - concrete is a plenty good enough conductor to result in electric shock (which is why GFI outlets are now a code requirement in the US for basements and garages). The tile itself, maybe not, but the grout and concrete under it, definitely yes. Dry sand is different, and in some places to ensure good conductance to earth for a grounding rod one needs to drip irrigate around the rod.

Comment: You have to also consider the capacitance and inductance of both your body and the tiles. Especially with alternating current, electricity will flow in and out of you as the charge held on you and the floor's surface repeatedly builds up and dissipates, without necessarily being transmitted beyond the tiles.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: "Then why I'm getting electrocuted while standing on floor tiles?" If you'd been electrocuted, you'd be dead!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will surely work.

Typically the soil resistivity value is subject to great variation, due to moisture, temperature, and chemical content. Typical values are:    from 10 up to 1000 (Ω-m)

For concrete, the resistivity is about 1 Ω-m. This is why, when you stand on a floor with a current source in one hand, you will feel a current (btw don't try this). The reason you don't get a shock, while wires are beneath walls of your house is that those wires have a less resistance path into the ground (called earthing).

Comment: I don't think your explanation about wires beneath walls valid. I think the reason is that the wires are insulated with rubber and only the plastic outlet is touching their contacts and plastic and rubber are not conducting.

Comment: yes you are correct, that is why when insulation tears apart in some area, then metallic taps gives you a shock